# Run a cron script at 1:00 PM UTC every day

Tags: cron

i need to run a cron at 1:00 PM UTC every day, is this the right crontab for UTC ?

0 1 * * *

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it should be in 24 hour format so

```
0 13 * * *
```

Comment: This will run the job at 1pm of whatever time zone the server is configured to. May or may not be UTC, most likely won't be.

Answer (score 9):

The timezone within which cron jobs are scheduled by default, is based upon the default system timezone (/etc/timezone). Depending upon your distribution, you may be able to set `CRON_TZ` in your crontab.

If your system default timezone is UTC then `0 1 * * *` is correct.

You can add a job like the following to your crontab to determine which timezone cron is using:

```
0 * * * * date > /tmp/date.out
```